# Collineations of projective spaces and isomorphisms of fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gn.general-topology, projective-geometry, fields

For a (topological) field $F$ by $FP^2$ we denote the projective plane, i.e., the quotient space of $F^3\setminus\{0\}^3$ by the equivalence relation $\vec x\sim\vec y$ iff $\vec x=\lambda\vec y$ for some $\lambda\in F\setminus\{0\}$.

A *line* in $FP^2$ is the image of $L\setminus\{0\}^3$ for some 2-dimensional linear subspace $L$ of $F^3$.

I need a reference to the following results, which (I hope) are true and known:

> **Theorem 1.** Two fields $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a line-preserving bijection between the projective planes $F_1P^2$ and $F_2P^2$.
>
> **Theorem 2.** Two topological fields $F_1$ and $F_2$ are topologically isomorphic if and only if there exists a line-preserving homeomorphism between the projective planes $F_1P^2$ and $F_2P^2$.

**Remark.** For finite fields, Theorem 1 holds in a stronger form: *two finite fields $F_1$, $F_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a bijection between the projective planes $F_1P^2$ and $F_2P^2$.*

Comment: The tag (geometry) is deprecated on MO, see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). Probably it could be replaced by some other suitable tag. (Or omitted entirely - as there already is a tag for algebraic geometry.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I noticed that the tag "geometry" is deprecated, but the system did not guggest anything more appropriate (now searching through all tags I found the appropriate tag "projective-geometry").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 1 is due to Hilbert and proven in Hartshorne's [book](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.475.3070&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on projective planes. In fact, every choice of projective plane and 4 points in that plane, with no 3 in a line, gives an explicit construction of a "ternary ring" (a weakened notion of ring), and if the projective plane is defined over a field, that ring is the field.

If Theorem 2 is known to be true, I would guess you would find it in H. Salzmann et. al., **Compact Projective Planes With an Introduction to Octonion Geometry**, but I am travelling so I can't check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Concerning Theorem 2 and the book of Salzmann, probably you are right. Unfortunately, google book does not show the necessary pages (212-232) on which there is a proof of topological version. So, I will wait for a more extensive answer.